# Is there a way to access logic app parameter inside a custom javascript action?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app that is using a custom javascript action. How can I access a logic app parameter from within the javascript code?

I have defined a `BatchSize` parameter:

```
"parameters": {
  // lots of stuff
  "BatchSize": {
    "type": "int"
  }
}
```

and the custom javascript action:

```
const data = workflowContext.actions.API_A_ACTION.outputs.body;
const dataLength = data.length;
const batchedData = [];
const batchSize = 1000; // this is what I would like to set from the BatchSize parameter

for (let i = 0; i < dataLength; i += batchSize) {
    const batch = data.slice(i, i + batchSize);
    batchedData.push(batch);
}

return batchedData;
```

Is there a way to access the parameters? The logic app documentation only mentions referencing triggers and actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly but you can add a compose action with the workflow parameter as input, and reference the output of compose in inline code.

Answer (score 0):

```
workflowContext.actions.Initialize_variable_pageSize.inputs.variables[0].value
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.