# How to access the parameters of the LogicApp in javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-logic-apps

My LogicApp has some parameters defined and I need to access the param values in the Javascript step.

I've tried `workflowContext.workflow.parameters.MyParam` and `workflowContext.workflow.parameters('MyParam')`, but none of them work.

How should I access the parameter values?

Comment: try workflowContext.action.parameters.MyParam

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to access logic app parameter inside a custom javascript action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214296/is-there-a-way-to-access-logic-app-parameter-inside-a-custom-javascript-action)